# Select first picture, not random, in a PHP code

Tags: php

The code below prints out all IMG tags in a blog post and then displays one image at random. How can I make the code so that it always shows the first image?

```
$DOM = new DOMDocument();

$string =
'Test hei
<img src="bild1e1">
string
<img src="bilde2" />
Mere tekst her........
<img src="bilde3" />
<img src="bilde4" />
fffffff
';

preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+>/i', $string, $var);

echo 'Det finnes totalt <strong>' . count($var[0]) . '</strong> img-tager i stringen. Disse ble funnet:<br>';

foreach($var[0] as $id => $value)
        echo '#' . ($id+1) . ': ' . htmlspecialchars($value) . '<br>';

echo '<br><br>';

$randomPic = array_rand($var[0], 1);

$DOM->loadHTML($var[0][$randomPic]);
$tag = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($tag as $i)
        echo '<strong>Random bilde-URL:</strong> ' . $i->getAttribute('src');
```

Comment: Clue: `array_rand(): Pick one or more random entries out of an array.`

Comment: @RelevantUsername Not to be aggressive, but I've always try to find a solution before I ask others for help. This time i could not figure it out by my self.

Answer (score 2):

```
$DOM->loadHTML($var[0][$randomPic]);
```

should then be

```
$DOM->loadHTML($var[0][0]);
```